# Create managed properties using CSOM on-premise

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, csom, sharepoint-on-prem, managed-property

I am looking for a simple PowerShell script that creates a managed property and maps it to a crawled property via CSOM for SharePoint on-premise. Is this even possible?

Comment: are you putting it into an App or something? Powershell is doable

Comment: Actually I am looking for a PowerShell script that uses CSOM :)

Answer (score 2):

Per my knowledge, CSOM can't provide a method to achieve this requirement currently, as a workaround, we can create a custom web service or REST service(SharePoint 2013) and use Server Object Model to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSOM in PowerShell script. For more information, refer to the articles below.

List Item Operations Using CSOM with PowerShell For SharePoint Online.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/list-item-operations-using-csom-with-powershell-for-sharepoi/

Use CSOM from PowerShell.

https://soerennielsen.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/use-csom-from-powershell/

And you also could create managed properties by PowerShell script according to the article below.

How To Create Managed Property In SharePoint 2013 Using PowerShell.

http://sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Create-Managed-Property-in-SharePoint-2013-using-PowerShell

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know you can use "CSOM in PowerShell" and you can create managed properties with Powershell on servers, but the question is "can we create Managed Properties using CSOM via PowerShell on the client side?"